# appium - testing web app using XCode through CircleCI

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, appium, circleci

I'm running into a problem when I try to run some tests using appium through CircleCI. I want to test a web app through CircleCI using xcode to host the simulator. I know CircleCI allows you to build an OSX environment. But I was wondering if there was another way to test it without needing to build the OSX through CircleCI.

Here is the error that I'm getting when I run the tests through Appium on CircleCI:

```
.1) Failure/Error: page.set_rack_session(hash)

      Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
        An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find path to Xcode by symlinks located in /var/db/xcode_select_link, or /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link
```

If anyone knows what's going on here, please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

circle.yml

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 0.12
  xcode:
    version: 7.3
  ruby:
    version: 2.3.0
  pre:
    - wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.22/chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/bin

database:
  override:
    - mv ci/database.yml config/database.yml
    - bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace

dependencies:
  pre:
    - gem install bundler
    - npm install appium

test:
  pre:
    - appium:
        background: true
  override:
    - CI_NAME=circle_ci RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake mobile nodes=4 --trace:
        parallel: true
```

Comment: What does your code look like? [mcve]

Comment: @Håken Lid I posted the Circle.yml file. Is that what you're asking for? I have appium working with xcode locally. It's CircleCI that is giving me the problems.